# Tildes sobre las letras mayúsculas

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, uso-de-mayúsculas

¿Cuál es la regla acerca del uso de las tildes sobre las letras mayúsculas? ¿Cuándo se debe ponerlas y cuándo no? ¿Y la regla siempre ha sido igual, o es algo que ha cambiado en el pasado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo correcto es usar siempre tildes sobre las letras mayúsculas. ¿Por qué? La tilde diacrítica es una marca ortográfica que indica una prescripción de la pronunciación (la prosodia) de una palabra y su remoción altera tal pronunciación. En fin, no es opcional.

Las reglas de acentuación del castellano son sencillas en principio pero llenas de excepciones. Un excelente resumen lo provee [Miguel Angel Monjas Llorente](http://web.archive.org/web/20110720150147/http://www.dat.etsit.upm.es/~mmonjas/acentos.html) y las correcciones y modificaciones hechas por la RAE desde la redacción de tal documento están en [su sitio web](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000018.nsf/%28voAnexos%29/arch8100821B76809110C12571B80038BA4A/%24File/CuestionesparaelFAQdeconsultas.htm#ap22).

> Las letras mayúsculas deben escribirse con tilde si les corresponde llevarla según las reglas de acentuación gráfica del español, tanto si se trata de palabras escritas en su totalidad con mayúsculas como si se trata únicamente de la mayúscula inicial:
>
> *Su hijo se llama Ángel.
>
>     ADMINISTRACIÓN
>
>     ATENCIÓN, POR FAVOR.*
>
> La Real Academia Española nunca ha establecido una norma en sentido contrario.

Comment: Es mejor que incluyas en tu respuesta los puntos clave de esos enlaces, ya que los enlaces se pueden romper y por tanto tu respuesta no tendría mucho sentido.

Comment: Y bienvenido a Spanish.SE (:

Comment: Lo haría pero estoy corto de tiempo hoy :-) Seguiré tu consejo en las próximas ocasiones.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. ¿Este es el caso también con palabras donde la tilde no altera la pronunciación (por ejemplo, *QUE* vs. *QUÉ*)?

Comment: @jrdioko Da igual que tipo de tilde sea (el caso que indicas ahora se llama "diacrítica"), debes ponerla siempre, es parte de la ortografía.

Answer (score 2):

Cómo dicen [en esta otra respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2812/24236) lo correcto es tildar las mayúsculas. Lo que pasaba era que antaño era complicado hacerlo en las imprentas por lo que las mayúsculas estaban eximidas de tal requisito.